# Email template font not working on tablet and phone devices

Tags: html, css, fonts, mailchimp, email-templates

Agency FB font works fine on desktop view on my email template when I send it out but in the device view it reverts back to the PT-sans.
I have applied the Agency FB font anywhere it says font family and I included the url link too. I use MailChimp to send the emails out, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp's docs state that support for custom fonts in emails is limited.

> **Elements to Avoid > Custom Fonts**
>
> MailChimp’s Drag and Drop Editor provides web-safe fonts only. Most email clients don’t support CSS properties like @font-face, @import, and that import custom fonts into web pages. For consistent display, use web-safe fonts.
>
> Or use images to display custom-font headlines, and include the body content as text. Without this balance of text and images, spam filters can flag your campaign.

from [Limitations of HTML Email](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email)

Perhaps they are trying to protect you from seeing a preview different than what most of your users will see.  However it does seem you can override this default with a custom template:

> Note
>
> If you’re comfortable with coding or if you have access to a developer, you can design custom coded templates that contain HTML elements with limited email client support, but we don’t always recommend it. Keep in mind that MailChimp support agents won’t be able to help you troubleshoot issues with your custom code.

Update: In the custom template docs (see [*Experimenting with Web Fonts*](http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/)), they do discourage use, but claim `<link>`, `@import`, `@font-face`, etc will work as expected in mail clients whose browsers do support custom fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The thing is, when I sent it out to a few test emails and opened them up on my desktop it's how I want it so why is working when opened in the desktop view but not for tablet and phones devices? It's a purchased template from Themeforest, I've added the font to it

Comment: @ font-face {
font-family: 'Agency FB'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Agency FB'), local('Agency FB'), url(' fontbureau.com/fonts/AgencyFB') format('truetype');
}

Comment: @doc1118 It seems like your CSS is fine. Perhaps it would be best to contact the theme's author for technical support.  Without knowing more about the structure of the code, it's hard to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think is more matter of what email client (or browser) you are using on mobile device, unfortunately it's highly possible that on older devices etc, you won't be able to get your font, especially in old mail mobile clients,

here is something what I consider as a quite ok solution ( yep, not the best one probably ), but if your mail looks good in Outlook 2010 on your desktop, then it should be ok in most of the other clients/browsers,
Outlook 2010 is could be such a pain, that if you make things work in it, that should cover the other environments